# Nodejs post continually loading

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing a server and on post it saves the the req.body to a file with fs.

The client page continues to load on submit, does the writefile need to be asynchronous and if so what should the callback look like and why is the page still loading.

```
app.post('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    fs.writeFileSync('data.txt', JSON.stringify(req.body))
})
```

Is this because I don't send a response?

Comment: Okay, so sending a response and changing it to an async function will improve my server?

Comment: yup. one would tell the client the server is done processing the request, the other would prevent said route from being a huge bottleneck for the entire server.

Comment: So when I send a response it changes to another page, I would like to send a response but stay on the same page. Is that possible?

Comment: well,  yeah, that's what ajax does.

Comment: @Sprout Would you consider accepting my answer, below?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is because you are not sending a response. Express will not automatically send a response, so when you post to that endpoint, you must return a response or else the request will hang.

The file write does not have to be async, but it should be. The modern way to do this is to use promises, something like...

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.writeFile('data.txt', JSON.stringify(req.body), (err) => 
    {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(data);
    }
}).then(
    (success) => res.send(success)
).catch(
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send();
    }
 );
```

If you don't want to do it async (you don't need to if it's a low-performance site), just do:

```
app.post('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    fs.writeFileSync('data.txt', JSON.stringify(req.body))
    res.send({"status": 200});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine besides neglecting to send a response. If you do not end the connection by sending a response, or manually calling `res.end()`, your server will hang and the client making the request will timeout.

Calling `res.send()` will end the connection for you, and send a response to the client to let them know at least the status of the request.

Sending back just a string should not cause the page to reload.

```
app.post('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    fs.writeFileSync('data.txt', JSON.stringify(req.body))
    // Set status code to 200, send string response
    res.status(200).send('Ok');
})
```